# Unexpected sum(list) behavior in Python with large list of primes with WinPython

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sum

My code returns something that I don't understand.
The algorithm is pretty straightforward, it adds prime numbers up to X into a list, then it sums all the numbers.

If the X is small, a cumulative loop and the sum(list) function give me the same answer but when X is large.... the results are different and I really don't get why!

EDIT : I run into issue on 3.3 with WinPython, I can't reproduce the issue in a stock distribution

Here is my code without the is_prime function but with the outputs of the tests I tried:

```
num_max=2*10**6
accu=[2]
total=2

#EDIT : here is the prime function
def is_prime(num):
    if num%2 == 0 and num != 2 or num%3 == 0 and num != 3:
        return False
    for i in range(1, int((num**0.5+1)/6+1)):
        if num%(6*i+1) == 0:
            return False
        if num%(6*i-1) == 0:
            return False        
    return True
# END OF EDIT

for i in range(3, num_max, 2):
    if is_prime(i) == True:
        accu.append(i)
        total += i

print(sum(accu)) # prints : 1179908154
print(total) # prints : 142913828922

# Test 1 --> The list "accu" seems to be created properly
tout=0
for num in accu:
    tout+=num
print(tout) # prints : 142913828922

# Test 2 --> Also, I don't understand why sum() works on the first part of the list!
print(sum(accu[:1000])) # prints : 3682913
tot=0
for i in range(1000):
    tot+=accu[i]
print(tot) # prints : 3682913
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @thefourtheye yeah, me too. Got equal results.

Comment: Show us the is_prime function.

Comment: I added back the prime function ;-)

Comment: Thanks to you guys, I narrowed the problem. The issue only occurs in my scientific distribution (WinPython 3.3.3.2), I cannot reproduce the problem in another distribution. Now I am down looking for what the heck leads to this weird behavior of the sum function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is importing `numpy.sum` to globals, which shadows Python's `builtins.sum`.

In this case `np.sum` calls the `ufunc` method `np.add.reduce`. In the C API this calls [`PyUFunc_GenericReduction`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c#L3617), which calls [`PyArray_FromAny`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1613) to convert your input list to an `ndarray`. This array's data type is set to `long` when the largest integer in the sequence is less than or equal to `LONG_MAX`, as is the case for `accu`. Subsequently the summation overflows because `LONG_MAX` is `2 ** 31 - 1` on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows. For example:

```
>>> max(accu)
1999993
>>> np.sum(accu)
1179908154
>>> np.sum(accu, dtype='int32')
1179908154
>>> np.sum(accu, dtype='int64')
142913828922
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This unexpected behavior is not so unexpected after all!  (sorry that I can't up you, I lack the reputation for that)

Comment: _sorry that I can't up you, I lack the reputation for that_ - done.

Comment: It's not Winpython's fault, I suspect that the console's or IPython's startup script did a `from pylab import *`. This was meant as a feature, but has now been abandoned due to errors like this.